# How to create the Interface used in "Google Play Music - Queue Interface"

Tags: android, android-studio, playlist, android-music-player

I want to Create an interface similar to the interface we see in the currently playing song queue of "Google Play Music" or any other music player

What is used over there, where we see list of songs in queue and we can slide a particular song up or down and there is a 3 dot option at the end of every song

what is used there - ListView or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Umano library to do this.

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/424

Comment: Thanks @CraZyDroid , that's quite helpful